# xorg.conf fails to build

Tags: lubuntu, lxdm

I am trying to build an xorg.conf file in Lubuntu 12.10 using a tty login.  I am following the documentation at [Lubuntu Workarounds](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Monitor_or_Screens).  It asks me to stop the lxdm service in order to run Xorg -configure to build a xorg.conf file, which I can then tweak to get my display's running correctly (without dead space).

The problem is that my computer claims that no LXDM service exists to "stop."  How should I go about killing the current session so I can run Xorg -configure?

I have been able to configure Xorg in a new display session (display1) but it doesn't find the drivers or correct display settings, perhaps because I cannot kill the current session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that my computer claims that no LXDM service exists to "stop." How should I go about killing the current session so I can run Xorg -configure?

Try:

```
service lightdm stop
```